# Tkinter and Matplotlib: relative position of canvas created by FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter, positioning

I'm creating a GUI that should display a few widgets (e.g. buttons and scales) on the left side of the main window (or 'root', created by `root=tk.Tk()`) and a graph on the right side. The graph would be created using matplotlib and the `FigureCanvasTkAgg()` backend (similar to what is found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)). Below is the code I've written so far.

```
import tkMessageBox, tkFileDialog
import sys
# Tkinter is for python 2; tkinter is for python 3
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk


class MainApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('App')
        # call the widgets
        self.okButton()
        self.quitButton()
        self.readDataButton()
        self.clearDataButton()
        self.velScale()
        self.canvas()

    # print messages on the screen
    def printMessage(self):
        if (self.data):
            print("Data is loaded and accessible from here (printMessage()).")
        else:
            print('No data loaded...')

    ### OK button
    def okButton(self):
        self.okButton = tk.Button(self, text='Test', command=self.printMessage)
        self.okButton.grid()

    ### Quit button
    def quitButton(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.confirmQuit)
        self.quitButton.grid()
    # confirm quitting
    def confirmQuit(self):
        answer = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="App", message="Do you really want to quit?")
        if (answer):
            self.quit()

    # Read data button
    def readDataButton(self):
        self.data = None
        self.readDataButton = tk.Button(self, text='Import data', command=self.readData)
        self.readDataButton.grid()
    # reading data
    def readData(self):
        import os
        fullPath = dataList = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='path/to/initialdir')
        dataDir = os.path.split(fullPath)[0]+'/'
        self.data = readData(fullPath)

    # Clear data from current session
    def clearDataButton(self):
        self.clearData = tk.Button(self, text='Clear data', command=self.confirmClearData)
        self.clearData.grid()
    # confirm clearing data
    def confirmClearData(self):
        answer = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="App", message="Are you sure you want to clear the loaded data?")
        if (answer):
            self.data = None
            tkMessageBox.showwarning(title="App", message="Data has been deleted.")

    # Velocity scale
    def velScale(self):
        self.velVar = tk.StringVar()
        velLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Scale value:", textvariable=self.velVar)
        velLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
        velScale = tk.Scale(self, from_=-500, to=+500, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, resolution=20,
                        sliderlength=20, showvalue=0,
                        length=200, width=20,
                        command=self.onVelScale)
        velScale.grid(row=5, column=0)
    # update velLabel
    def onVelScale(self, val):
        self.velVar.set("Scale value: {:+0.0f}".format(float(val)))

    # Canvas
    def canvas(self):
        import matplotlib
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
        from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
        from matplotlib.figure import Figure

        self.f = Figure(figsize=(4,2))
        self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        self.a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self.parent)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.parent)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600+10+10")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    MainApp(root).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    root.mainloop()
```

The result is this: [Screenshot of the App's main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGLuU.png). Using `.grid()` for the button and scale widgets works as expected (I can place them wherever I want by specifying `row` and `column`). However, I cannot have the same behavior for the canvas part. It seems that only `.pack()` will work with the canvas (and the result is shown in the link above).

Does anybody have any idea on how to workaround this? Or am I missing something?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: firstly i didn't think you need to call `show` when you are `grid`ing the figure, but secondly you have some code to be able to use `tkinter` in python 2 or 3, but you haven't changed you imports for filedialogs or message boxes, these also change between 2 and 3.

Comment: Hi, @JamesKent! Thanks for your comments. I have already changed the code to import `tkMessageBox` and `tkFileDialog` accordingly to the version of Python that is being used. Regarding your comment on `.grid()`, could you please elaborate a bit more? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with python3.3, I've changed your code to this:

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
# Tkinter is for python 2; tkinter is for python 3
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox, tkFileDialog

else:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox
    from tkinter import filedialog as tkFileDialog

class MainApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('App')
        # call the widgets
        self.okButton()
        self.quitButton()
        self.readDataButton()
        self.clearDataButton()
        self.velScale()
        self.canvas()

    # print messages on the screen
    def printMessage(self):
        if (self.data):
            print("Data is loaded and accessible from here (printMessage()).")
        else:
            print('No data loaded...')

    ### OK button
    def okButton(self):
        self.okButton = tk.Button(self, text='Test', command=self.printMessage)
        self.okButton.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")

    ### Quit button
    def quitButton(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.confirmQuit)
        self.quitButton.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nesw")
    # confirm quitting
    def confirmQuit(self):
        answer = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="App", message="Do you really want to quit?")
        if (answer):
            self.quit()

    # Read data button
    def readDataButton(self):
        self.data = None
        self.readDataButton = tk.Button(self, text='Import data', command=self.readData)
        self.readDataButton.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="nesw")
    # reading data
    def readData(self):
        import os
        fullPath = dataList = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='path/to/initialdir')
        dataDir = os.path.split(fullPath)[0]+'/'
        self.data = readData(fullPath)

    # Clear data from current session
    def clearDataButton(self):
        self.clearData = tk.Button(self, text='Clear data', command=self.confirmClearData)
        self.clearData.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky="nesw")
    # confirm clearing data
    def confirmClearData(self):
        answer = tkMessageBox.askyesno(title="App", message="Are you sure you want to clear the loaded data?")
        if (answer):
            self.data = None
            tkMessageBox.showwarning(title="App", message="Data has been deleted.")

    # Velocity scale
    def velScale(self):
        self.velVar = tk.StringVar()
        velLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Scale value:", textvariable=self.velVar)
        velLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
        velScale = tk.Scale(self, from_=-500, to=+500, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, resolution=20,
                        sliderlength=20, showvalue=0,
                        length=200, width=20,
                        command=self.onVelScale)
        velScale.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky="nesw")
    # update velLabel
    def onVelScale(self, val):
        self.velVar.set("Scale value: {:+0.0f}".format(float(val)))

    # Canvas
    def canvas(self):
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(4,2))
        self.a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        self.a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=2, row=1, rowspan=5, sticky="nesw")

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.parent)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600+10+10")
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    MainApp(root).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    root.mainloop()
```

to show what i meant about not calling `show` i also moved your matplotlib imports to the top of the file and changed the other imports to suit python 2/3, this seems to grid fine for me, can you clarify what it wasn't doing that you expected it to do? (if this still doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks, James Kent. Now I understand. However, the problem with `.grid()` remains: using `row` and `column` as arguments, I still cannot place the button/scale widgets on the left and the plot area on the right.

Comment: i can't believe i missed it, the problem is where you are trying to put the plot, you should be putting it into the frame, but instead you are trying to put it into the parent of the frame, as the frame is packed and the plot is gridded it goes into an endless loop trying to work out where to put everything, try the revised code above.

Comment: That was it, @James Kent! Now they can be "controlled" with the `.grid()` using the `row` and `column` options. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't get an error having canvas() function and calling FigureCanvasTkAgg as canvas

Comment: Thanks, Andre! I'll give it a shot when I get the chance.

Comment: Working on a similar problem with matplotlib, canvas, and grid and am seeing the functions named the same as the variables which causes me problems.